# Stack Exchange API Sandbox

Tags: support

Following [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18593/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-github-pull-requests-for-a-king-of-the-hill-challeng), I need a sandbox to try out the StackOverflow API for grabbing code from answers.

Please do not post answers to this question.

```html
<script src="https://ajfaraday.github.io/Thud/dist/data/tables.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><h2>Dwarf</h2><table> <thead> <tr> <th>Client</th> <th>Wins</th><th>Loses</th> <th>Score</th> </tr></thead> <tbody id="clients"> </tbody></table><script type='text/javascript'>  
league_table.dwarf.forEach( function(data_row){var row=$('<tr>'); var cell=$('<td>'); cell.html(data_row.name.substring(6)); row.append(cell); cell=$('<td>'); cell.html(data_row.win); row.append(cell); cell=$('<td>'); cell.html(data_row.lose); row.append(cell);row.append(cell);cell=$('<td>'); cell.html(data_row.score); row.append(cell); $('tbody#clients').append(row);});</script>
```

Comment: I'm here to add a comment to help you ensure that your code works even with comments posted

Comment: Thanks @Mathgeek. It shouldn't matter too much because I'm filtering out the comments, but it can't hurt to have a little noise here.

Comment: I tried a similar thing once and it caught comments instead of the answer once there were enough, so I figured an extra lob wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I am also here just to make it a bit harder for no obvious reason ...

Comment: If anyone's interested, the comments did not cause any problems with my importing process.

Comment: Then one with a code block: `f=_=>{throw 'AJFaraday';}` :)

Comment: @Bubbler You make a good point. I'm working on a fairly-paranoid importer script which should throw out answers which risk messing up the competition environment.

Comment: "Please ignore this question" tends to attract attention. Perhaps try "Stack Exchange API sandbox"? You can also go ahead and remove the first sentence. This is the perfect place to do this.

Comment: I've VTCed this as the challenge has now been posted and this question is no longer needed.

Comment: I've agreed with Shaggy, and VTCed. If you need this Sandbox again, I suggest mentioning this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240) for it to be reopened

Comment: I had meant to delete these to save you the effort, but apparently I'm not able to because of Shaggy's answer. Sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's my old one which I do not need any more. I'm creating a new similar one, and would use this instead except that there's answers from other people so I'm not allowed to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

## Imported

```
class {
  constructor(controller, utils) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.side = controller.side;
    this.utils = utils;
  }

  turn() {
    var target = this.controller.previous_move().to;
    var troll = this.controller.space_info(target.x, target.y).nearest_troll.pieces[0];
    this.controller.select_space(troll.x, troll.y);
    var space_info = this.controller.check_space(troll.x, troll.y);
    var closest_move = this.utils.closest_to(space_info.moves, target);
    this.controller.move(closest_move.x, closest_move.y);
  }

  end_turn() {
    var scores = this.controller.scores();
    this.controller.declare(scores.winning == 't');
  }

}
```

Comment: Care to add a Try It Online?

Comment: I could, although it would prove very little. Just that `Behaviours` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

## Invalid

```
class {
  constructor(controller, utils) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.side = controller.side;
    this.utils = utils;
  }

  turn() {
    // Oops! nothing here!
  }

  end_turn() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MoreJunk

```
throw 'ha ha haaa!';
```

Answer (score 1):

## Imported_duplicate

```
class {
  constructor(controller, utils) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.side = controller.side;
    this.utils = utils;
  }

  turn() {
    var target = this.controller.previous_move().to;
    var troll = this.controller.space_info(target.x, target.y).nearest_troll.pieces[0];
    this.controller.select_space(troll.x, troll.y);
    var space_info = this.controller.check_space(troll.x, troll.y);
    var closest_move = this.utils.closest_to(space_info.moves, target);
    this.controller.move(closest_move.x, closest_move.y);
  }

  end_turn() {
    var scores = this.controller.scores();
    this.controller.declare(scores.winning == 't');
  }

}
```

Posting at AJ's request.